# Restart fan in Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad, overheating, fan

The fan on my rather old (>5 years) Thinkpad sometimes stops working. Running the `sensors` command shows:

```
thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        65535 RPM
```

i.e. the number of revs goes crazy (the normal value is up to 4600 rpm).

I have tried running `pwmconfig` as suggested [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249157/manually-turn-on-cpu-fan), as well as the lengthy command presented [in this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311218/restart-fan-manually-in-linux). However, none of this worked, and to restart the fan I always had to restart the computer.

Is there possibly any other way to restart the fan?

Comment: Is the module thinkpad_acpi loaded? Check: `lsmod | grep think`

Comment: Sorry for late answer, it took me some time to reproduce this error. The output of your command gives three lines, the first and probably the only relevant one is
`thinkpad_acpi          81013  1`